# Machine learning -Validacion cruzada

Tags: python, validación, machine-learning, model

Tengo un conjunto de datos, a partir del cual quiero realizar un modelo. El mismo ya los dividí en X_train, y_train, X_test y y_test. Entonces, primero uso este código para preprocesar los datos y definir el estimador :(

```
# Identificación de columnas numéricas y categóricas
numeric_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['float64', 'int']).columns.to_list()
cat_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include=['object', 'category']).columns.to_list()


# Transformaciones para las variables numéricas
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
                        steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler())]
                      )

# Transformaciones para las variables categóricas
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(
                            steps=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))]
                          )

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
                    transformers=[
                        ('numeric', numeric_transformer, numeric_cols),
                        ('cat', categorical_transformer, cat_cols)
                    ],
                    remainder='passthrough'
                )

# Pipeline
# ==============================================================================

# Se combinan los pasos de preprocesado y el modelo en un mismo pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('preprocessing', preprocessor),
                 ('modelo', Ridge())])
```

pero tengo este error, ayuda por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: parece que `x_train` es un array de numpy, y vos lo estás tratando como algún otro tipo de variable. No sabría decirte exactamente qué tipo de variable tiene el argumento `columns` quizá un `dataFrame`  de `pandas`? En ese caso deberías ver por qué tu `x_train` es un array de numpy y no un dataframe

Comment: correcto, colums es un dataframe pero no tengo ni idea de como corregirlo :(((

Comment: El problema es que nó inlcuís de donde sale ese `x_train`. Vos esperás que sea un dataframe, pero algo de lo que hacés en el código que no pusiste lo convierte a un array de `numpy`